# Cannot execute anything in Xamarin Studio when writing code in D

Tags: d, xamarin-studio

I am using Xamarin Studio as a D environment. I followed all the instructions given [here](http://mono-d.alexanderbothe.com/?page_id=9), and the environment works OK. However, whenever I click the 'play' button in the corner, which is meant to build and run my project, regardless of which settings I give it, I can't get it to run. More specifically, the build succeeds, but then I get an error (which I also can't seem to read the entirety of), which starts with

"Cannot execute [name of my project]. The type initializer for 'MonoDevelop.Debugger.Gdb.D.ToStringExaminatio..."

I've tried searching for answers to this, but have found none. Any and all help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Xamarin Studio 4.1.7 on OSX, Mono 3.2.0 and Mono-D 0.5.3.7 and debugger adding 0.2.2, I can start the applications using 'Run without debugging' in the 'Run' menu.

I can't succeed in using the debugger, but I think is an OSX problem: should work on linux.